# Why does my window allow about a 25px scroll to the right when the browser(chrome) window is at its smallest width?

Tags: html, css

This sounds like a simple question but, basically in Chrome or Safari, my website http://www.fixedroi.com/ when the browser is minimized to its smallest width I am still able to scroll right 25px. ---That problem is fixed----  Now when I am on a mobile platform, there is about 25pixels on the right for some reason still that allow the page to scroll to the right.  I want to get rid of the excess pixels..  I feel like I messed up some of the css up..

Answer (score 2):

`.resultpic` and `.superiorwrap` seem to have right padding when it's hitting it's mobile breakpoints

Comment: How do I fix this?  Seems on the mobile/iphone 5 it isn't lining up correctly and still has that scroll to the right.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `padding-top: -40px;` design.css line 221 is the problem.

Comment: Thanks.. Removed.. It..  Still happening

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the right padding of .resultpic and .superiorwrap:

```
@media (max-width: 1068px)
.resultpic {
    float: left;
    width: 430px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 120px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}
.resultpic {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 650px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}



@media (max-width: 1068px)
.superiorwrap {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    padding-right: 37px;
}
.superiorwrap {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 150px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped..  Now I am receiving about 5ish pixels on the right side for some reason..

Comment: That's because there's still a right padding on .superiorwrap, on line 119.

Comment: Thanks.  Wonder why it disappeared on a desktop browser and now on an iPhone 5 it still has scrolling to the right and everything didn't go to an spect ratio of one.